# After registering my site in google webmaster, I cannot add the same domain in google push console

Tags: push-notification, google-search-console

I registered my site in google webmaster successfully: snapshot.xxx.xxx:3000. However, when I go to google app console and try to add this domain to push console for push notification, it claimed that I don't have a right to access this domain.

What is happening?

Comment: can you please clarify or include screenshots?

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically I registered my site in webmaster : snapshot.xxx.xxx:3000. In app console, google will not recognize snapshot.xxx.xxx:3000; instead, it will recognize snapshot.xxx.xxx

So, I just inout snapshot.xxx.xxx and this problem is fixed.